# How to avoid void type in generators Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using a generator in my code, that returns strings, but I'm facing the following problem:

```js
const pageUrl = generator.next().value;
const result = catalogPageParser(pageUrl);
```

Returning the error:

```
Argument of type 'string | void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

This is easily fixed by either modify the variable like this:

```js
const pageUrl = generator.next().value ?? "some valid url";
```

Or by modifying the signature of the `catalogPageParser` function. I do not like any of those solutions, but I cannot think of anything else. Any ideas about how to type that correctly?

I do not like the default value option because there's not a reasonable default value in my case. I also do not like the second because it does not make at all for the function to accept void as a possible argument.

### Example

```
function* someGenerator() {
  yield "url1";
  yield "url2";
}

function acceptsStringOnly(argument: string) {
  console.log(argument);
}

const value = someGenerator().next().value;
acceptsStringOnly(value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the result of an iterator can have no value if it has already ended. In those cases the property `done` is `false`. TypeScript can automatically narrow the type of the `value` property if you check `done`:

```
function* generator() {
    yield 'string1';
    yield 'string2';
    yield 'string3';
}

const iterator = generator();
const result = iterator.next();

let theString: string;

// This fails as in your example
theString = result.value;

if (!result.done) {
    // this works
    theString = result.value;
} else {
    // whatever you have to do if the iterator has ended
}
```

So the solution to your case can be: 1) check first if `done` is `true` and act accordingly (early return, throw, whatever you need); 2) if you know that the iterator will *always* return a value you can use a non-null assertion.

---

Your current solution using `??` is likely a good one also, but it of course depends on your needs. One disadvantage I can think of would be that you don't have a proper default value in that context. Managing the case that iterator has ended is, IMHO, a better approach in the general case.