# How to specify type of an infinite generator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is a sample JavaScript code:

```
/**
 * Generates the sequence of numbers.
 * 
 * @param {number} i - The first number.
 * @yields {number} The next number.
 */
function* gen(i) {
  while (true) {
    yield i++;
  }
}

const g = gen(1);

// 1st case
// No error here
const n = g.next();
if (!n.done) {
  const x = n.value * 2;
  console.log(x);
}

// 2nd case
// Error:
//   The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
// Other variants of the error for other expressions:
//   Type 'number | void' is not assignable to type 'number'.
//   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'
const y = g.next().value * 2;
console.log(y)
```

`gen` function generates an infinte sequence of numbers. So I don't need to check whether it's finished.

Is it possible to remove the typecheck error in the 2nd case? Here is a similar question: [How to avoid void type in generators Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545038/how-to-avoid-void-type-in-generators-typescript). The following suggestions was given:

> 1. check first if done is true and act accordingly (early return, throw, whatever you need);
> 2. if you know that the iterator will always return a value you can use a non-null assertion.

But I don't want to check `done`. And I can't add a non-null assertion, because it's JavaScript, not TypeScript. Could you suggest how to remove the error?

Here is `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "module": "es2022",
    "target": "es2021",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to check for `done`? In the 1st case, you do check for `done`. And how are you getting a ts error if you're not using ts?

Comment: I don't want to check for `done` because it's a useless complication of the code just to make TypeScript happy. The code is written in JavaScript, but one can use TypeScript to check types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html The types are inferred from code or jsdoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is protecting you from [`g.return()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return). There does not exist a generator function which can never be `done`. The `Generator.prototype.return()` method can even be implicitly called when using generator objects in [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops:

```js
function* gen(i) {
  while (true) {
    yield i++;
  }
}

const g = gen(1);

for (const n of g) {
  if (n > 5) break;
  console.log(n);
}

console.log(g.next());
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got it. Actually my generator (in the real application) yields random numbers. Maybe I should use a plain function instead of the generator... The generator interface looks not very suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with Typescript, since it is supposed to catch potential code errors like this.

If you're absolutely certain that the generator will not return a null value, you could explicitly write out the type like so:
`const y = (g.next().value as number) * 2;`

Comment: I can't use type casting, because it's JavaScript code, not TypeScript.

Comment: it seems like a gap in typescript. it's possible to create never ending generators, and in some cases even recommended. redux-sagas comes to mind